# Android source code, I can't get real source but only bare repository

Tags: android, git, ubuntu

I am starting to work on Android source code in Ubuntu and even if I am expert in Android App development, this part of Android is quite new to me so apologize for any stupid questions.

I started by creating my master branch locally with the following commands:

```
$ mkdir master
$ cd master
$ wget http://git.[myandroidrom]/repo
$ chmod +x repo
```

All working as expected, I end up with a folder called **master** and a file called **repo** inside it.
Second step I started the synchronization of my source code:

```
$ ./repo init -u http://git.[myandroidrom]/manifest -b [my specific rom branch]
$ ./repo sync
```

It took a while (few hours) after I got the folder **master** populated with all the folders mentioned into the Android source code documentation but they are all .git folders. So quite useless because in order to compile Android I need the real source code which is somehow packed into those .git folders.

What should be the next step to extract the content of this repository?

Comment: Are asking about [Downloading the source](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) of AOSP?

Comment: Yes but after sync is done I see only git folders, not the real source

Answer (score -1):

So actually the command repo sync create a folder .repo which contains the .git structure of android. If in the repo init you don't specify with -b a branch it will download the master branch.
After that, in order to have the real code you need to git clone the folder.

Example, I run the following command:

```
$ repo sync build
```

where build is the name of my project folder and in the root working directory I have now the source code for the folder build. 
More info can be found at this URL:
https://source.android.com/source/developing.html